# Coordinate yourself!

Tags: visual, board-games

Task is simple. Get coordinates from the two pictures below. You **don't** have to know game rules to solve it :)

[image: Image of the riddle]

Hint

> It's nothing complicated, think like a child

Comment: How many expansions do you have?

Comment: don't vandalise your post

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Puzzling community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: Should one of the 2 blue guys (meeples) be a big guy? Because they both look regular (none of the other figures have duplicates on the board)

Answer (score 1):

The image on the left looks vaguely like

> Australia

With the orange bordered square in the centre around the location of

> Alice Springs

I'm still not sure about the image on the right.